# Редирект без разрешения

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс

Есть у меня сайт на битриксе, там есть модуль оплаты сбербанк. По факту, после оформления заказа он отправляет на страницу с кнопкой оплатить и т.д., но потом должна редиректить на страницу оплаты в самом сбербанке, но все браузеры блокируют и просят разрешения, а редирект так и не происходит пока пользователь не разрешит, как без разрешения сразу редиректить. В самом модуле нашел код

```
<script>
    window.open('<?=$arParams["PATH_TO_PAYMENT"]?>?ORDER_ID=<?=$orderAccountNumber?>&PAYMENT_ID=<?=$paymentAccountNumber?>');
</script>
```

через location делал - все равно спрашивает

Comment: window.open это не редирект, а попап. Попапы можно открывать только при явном действии пользователя, например в обработчике клика

Comment: Редирект по умолчанию браузеры должны блокировать, как вы себе представляете обратное? Зашли на один сайт, а вышли с третьего и без всякого взаимодействия.

Comment: @Leonid вообще-то именно так всё и работает. Например какая-нибудь авторизация гуглом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать данную конструкцию для явного редиректа:

```
window.location.href = 'ссылка'
```